Error in running default project of Android Studio
I have installed Android Studio in my Ubuntu desktop, and went through the steps of the setup wizard. I tried to do the default project Greetings Card. In the application page one unable to load stats. How to fix this issue?
I got the error after overriding stats error.
Error loading Default project  
Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.compiler.configuration.KotlinPluginLayout


Errors related to "unable to load stats" might appear in Android Studio's LogCat or Event Log. Look there for more specific details about the issue. Check View -> Tool Windows -> Logcat for error logs or warnings which can provide clues. Then please comment or edit your question with the results that you found.

I got the error after overriding stats error.

Error loading Default project Couldnot initialize class org.jetbrainß.kotlin.idea.compiler.configuration.KotlinPluginLayout
